# Translation of それを持って来させる

Tags: translation, て-form, causation

I have the following translation for class.

```
勉強しなかった悪い学生に、
家で漢字を三百回書かせて、
それを持って来させて、
それから、教室の前に一時間立たせた。
```

So far I have the following.

```
Bad students who didn't study
I made them write kanji 300 times at home and
.... and
after that, I made them stand at the front of the classroom for an hour.
```

That 3rd line I am really having problems with. I see the "to make someone" structure with the 来させて. And then the て form of "to have" with the 持って. So "I made them to have this and come"? Or I think て and 来る　can mean to come to a point. So maybe "so as to make them get to have this" like in an "understand this" sort of way?  I just don't know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

持ってくる means to bring something with you (hold/carry than come) so the 3rd line is something like
 "...and had them bring it back (to class)"